# How to set specific intervals in histogram plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, intervals, bins

I want to plot a histogram with a binwidth of 4. I am not able to fix the intervals of these data. I want my bins to start from x = 28 and have intervals of 4 from there on. For ex - 28-32, 32-36, 36-40 and so on. How do I set specific intervals and fix a start value for the histograms?

```
crushing_strength <- c(40,37.9,29,31.7,39.3,40.7,42.7,40,50.3,
                                  33.8,39.3,42.1,45.5,41.4,47.6,38.6,35.9,
                                  41.4,44.1,40,40.7,42.1,38.6,36.5,40.7)
test_no <- seq(1:25)

data_example <- data.frame(test_no,crushing_strength)


ggplot(data_example, aes(x = crushing_strength))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth=4)+
  scale_x_continuous()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your desired breaks via the `breaks=` argument of `geom_histogram`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_example, aes(x = crushing_strength)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(28, 52, 4)) +
  scale_x_continuous()
```

[image]